# vscode typescript intellisense not working for evernote

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, evernote

I've installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/evernote to my project to get evernote types definition.

When I import Evernote as follow

```
import { Evernote } from 'evernote';
const client = new Evernote.Client({
  consumerKey: '...',
  consumerSecret: '...',
  sandbox: true,
  token: '...'
});
```

Vscode recognize Evernote and suggests me autocompletion and lists all the available methods and objects.
However, When I run my project, it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined

When I import Evernote as below, I can run my app:

```
import * as Evernote from 'evernote';
```

But I don't get the autocompletion working.

How should I import my evernote module to make it works properly?

I've also tried

```
import Evernote = require('evernote');
```

but it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `import { Evernote } from 'evernote'` is importing the named export `Evernote`.
- `import * as Evernote from 'evernote'` is special TS syntax to import the module.
- `import Evernote from 'evernote'` is importing the default export (note, you'll need to enable `esModuleInterop` or `syntheticDefaultImports` in your TSConfig.

You're looking for `import { Client } from 'evernote'`.