# Typescript - Intellisense does not properly suggest imported modules properties

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following piece of code:

```js
import * as Evernote from 'Evernote';

console.log(typeof Evernote.Client);
```

This returns me `function` as expected.

However, I have the following error is VSCode:

[image]
This error expects me to use Client as follow:

```js
import * as Evernote from 'Evernote';

console.log(typeof Evernote.Evernote.Client);
```

My former question ([vscode typescript intellisense not working for evernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566171/vscode-typescript-intellisense-not-working-for-evernote)) confirmed me that the proper way of importing Evernote is with the *. How should I solve the issue with VSCode ?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is unable to find Type Definitions for this library.
Try installing the types for Evernote: [@types/evernote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/evernote)

Comment: I've already installed @types/evernote
That's why autocomplete and type checking works when I use `Evernote.Evernote.Client`..